# Is it possible to change the state of a container with an external function or in a child without passing in a function?

Tags: reactjs

The standard onChange behavior, in React, I would like to have this behavior in the input/TextField component, instead of repeating the code every time I use the component, and able to update the parent container's state.

Otherwise it would be nice to be able to just import the behavior to use it, instead of having to rewrite it every time I am creating a new container with input/TextField component.

```js
onChange(e) {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
```

Any thoughts/solutions? (Even for why this may be a bad idea.)

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to set state within a child component and have the parent component be able to read that state?

Comment: Put an example of the behaviour

Comment: I want the child to be able to set/update the state of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great idea and done a lot, try passing a callback function to Child component.

In this example, a `Parent` passes `setValue` to its child component.

`Child` component updates its parent state using the callback function `setValue` as aspected.

```js
function Child({ onChange }) {
  return <input onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} />;
}

function Parent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("I'm a Parent");
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <Child onChange={setValue} />
    <>
  );
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit hungry-dubinsky-j2wbo]

Comment: That would be no different than:
onChange={e => this.setState([e.target.name]: e.target.value)}

Though I definitely appreciate learning that, since I haven't been keeping up with new React features for a while.

I am hoping the child can somehow manipulate the parent's state without any code in the parent outside of <Child name={key} />